# Rails source location of method without an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I find the source location of a method without an object? E.g. I want to find the source location of the Active Record's find method, or the Machinist gem's make method. These methods are usually called without any object.

Comment: Ref to find method code: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'active_record'
m=ActiveRecord::Base.method :find 
# => #<Method: Class(ActiveRecord::Querying)#find>

m.source_location
#  => ["/<snip>/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/querying.rb", 4]
```